# [src]="sermon?.sermonVideo" not working. it works with pictures though

Tags: html, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

so… i’m trying to get a video on my page from a data.json

It is strange, if i source the video directly, it works fine.

here is my code, then i’ll explain more.

html

```
<div class="sermon-background">
<div class="topRoom" >
  <video controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
   <source [src]="sermon?.sermonVideo" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
<div class="topRoom2">
  <svg width="100%" height="calc(1vw + 1vh + 6vmin)">
    <rect width="100%" height="calc(1vw + 1vh + 6vmin)" style="fill:rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.548);stroke-width:0;stroke:rgb(60,200,160)" />
    <text dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="55%" fill="white" style="font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + 2vmin); font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif; font-weight: calc(.1vw + .1vh + .1vmin); text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.445), 2px 2px 0px rgba(44, 44, 44,0.445), 3px 3px 0px rgba(44, 44, 44, 0.445) ">{{sermon?.name}}</text>
  </svg>
</div >
<img [src]="sermon?.profilePic" [alt]="sermon?.name">
```

so, the profilePic from the same place using the same method loads fine.

also, if I use “src=assets/videos/Sermon1.mp4”, that works fine.

here is my data.json

```
      "name": "Finding Grace",
  "profilePic": "/assets/img/stuffs/PastorEvaFace.jpg",
  "sermonVideo": "/assets/videos/Sermon1.mp4",
  "about": "Learn to fnid Grace in every circumstance and realize just how much God has given you.",
  "sum": "God has given us grace, we just need to open our eyes.",
  "location": "Everywhere",
  "id": "1"
```

anyone have any idea why it can’t run the video? profilePic runs fine...

I get the error "No video with supported format and mime type not found" when i try video

Thank in advance for taking a peak

Comment: Could you please use codepen.io snippets or S.O. runnable scripts to allow other tosee what errors your code fragment produces. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the returned path value

the path in data.json starts with "/" (absolute path)
`"sermonVideo": "/assets/videos/Sermon1.mp4"`

whereas the one that you are using for testing does not have that 
 `“src=assets/videos/Sermon1.mp4”`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I tried messing with it more, but it still doesn't work. I changed the file path up but no luck. Thanks for your suggestion though.